# Error in installing python3-tk package

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I get the following Error while installing python3-tk by typing :

```
apt-get install python3-tk

Need to get 34.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 150 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  python3-tk
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main python3-tk amd64 3.4.3-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-stdlib-extensions/python3-tk_3.4.3-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
I tried to run apt-get update and tried with --fix-missing but of no use. Can anybody help me figure out the way to solve this or provide alternate method to download tkinter for python3 ?
```

Comment: `apt-get update`?

Comment: you should just be able to import tkinter without installing extra?

Comment: No, it says no module named _tkinter

Comment: I had a similar problem and `apt-get update --fix-missing` worked for me. However, I used `python-tk`, not `python3-tk`, and I'm not sure whether `--fix-missing` was needed.

Comment: @MattKleinsmith the answer works perfectly on windows! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Ubuntu, try adding the deadsnakes ppa first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, as per answers from a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815874/importerror-no-named-tkinter-please-install-the-python3-tk-package), depending on which python version you are using and your project configuration:

Install tkinter for Python3.x.x:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

For Python 3.6 virtual environment with Python 3.5 as the "system" python:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk
```

'In general, it seems if one is using a virtual environment with a python of a different version than that of ones base machine, one must install tk for the version of python used in the virtual environment':

```
sudo apt install python3.x-tk
```

'Where 3.x would match the version of the virtual environment.'

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to install `tkinter` separately. Just use `from tkinter import *`